# Override CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList with new dependence injection

Tags: magento2, overrides, preference

Here is my di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="Custom\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

My current code

```
    <?php
    namespace Custom\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
    use Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as HttpContext;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
    use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
    use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder as SqlBuilder;
    use Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        HttpContext $httpContext,
        SqlBuilder $sqlBuilder,
        Rule $rule,
        Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        array $data = [],
        Json $json = null,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory = null,
        EncoderInterface $urlEncoder = null,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository = null,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $productCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProductVisibility,
            $httpContext,
            $sqlBuilder,
            $rule,
            $conditionsHelper,
            $data,
            $json,
            $layoutFactory,
            $urlEncoder,
            $categoryRepository
        );
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function getCategoryName($category_ids) {

        $last_id = end($category_ids);
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $categoryInstance = $this->categoryRepository->get($last_id, $storeId);

        return $categoryInstance->getName();


    }
}
```

i want to add store manager in constructor the above constructor didn't work, do anyone know how to add new dependency in constructor?

Comment: It should work. Did you clean `generated` folder and run `compile` command?

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code.

```
 <?php
namespace Custom\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;

class ProductList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface 
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * ProductList constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder $sqlBuilder
     * @param \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule $rule
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     * @param Json|null $json
     * @param LayoutFactory|null $layoutFactory
     * @param EncoderInterface|null $urlEncoder
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder $sqlBuilder,
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule $rule,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = [],
        Json $json = null,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory = null,
        EncoderInterface $urlEncoder = null
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $productCollectionFactory, $catalogProductVisibility, $httpContext, $sqlBuilder, $rule, $conditionsHelper, $data, $json, $layoutFactory, $urlEncoder);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    public function getCategoryName($category_ids) {
    
        $last_id = end($category_ids);
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $categoryInstance = $this->categoryRepository->get($last_id, $storeId);
        return $categoryInstance->getName();
    }

}
```

And perform the required commands.

Comment: $categoryInstance = $this->categoryRepository->get($last_id, $storeId); but i can't make use like this, there is an error $this->categoryRepository is null

Comment: @hkguile please check now, I have updated the code as per your requirement on `categoryRepository`.

Comment: @hkguile Still do you have any issues?